# sub linq query is making this take a very long time, how can I make this faster?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a list of employees that I build like this:

```
var employees = db.employees.Where(e => e.isActive == true).ToList();

var latestSales = from es in db.employee_sales.Where(x => x.returned == false);
```

Now what I want is a result like this:

```
int employeeId
List<DateTime> lastSaleDates
```

So I tried this, but the query takes a very very long time to finish:

```
var result = 
  (from e in employees
   select new EmployeeDetails
   {
      EmployeeId = e.employeeId,
      LastSaleDates = 
           (from lsd in latestSales.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == e.EmployeeId)
                                   .Select(x => x.SaleDate)
            select lsd).ToList()
   };
```

The above works, but literally takes 1 minute to finish.

What is a more effecient way to do this?

Comment: have you run the query more than once?  I believe the first query takes significantly longer due to caching

Comment: @Jonesy When you execute a DB query for each item in a query result it tends to be slow; caching or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calls to `ToList` are pulling things into memory.  You should opt to build up a Linq expression instead of pulling an entire query into memory.  In your second query, you are issuing a new query for each employee, since your are then operating in the Linq-to-objects domain (as opposed to in the EF).  Try removing your calls to `ToList`.

You should also look into using Foreign Key Association Properties to makes this query a lot nicer.  Association properties are some of the most powerful and useful parts of EF.  Read more about them [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnforum/archive/2010/05/07/foreign-key-association-in-entity-framework-4.aspx).  If you have the proper association properties, your query can look as nice as this:

```
var result = from e in employees
      select new EmployeeDetails
    {
        EmployeeId = e.employeeId,
        LastSaleDates = e.AssociatedSales
    }
```

You might also consider using a join instead.  Read about Linq's `Join` method [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9).

Comment: it was the call to ToList which was pulling into memory, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use join to get all data in single query

```
var result = from e in db.employees.Where(x => x.isActive)
             join es in db.employee_sales.Where(x => x.returned)
                  on e.EmployeeId equals es.EmployeeId into g
             select new {
                  EmployeeId = e.employeeId,
                  LastSaleDates = g.Select(x => x.SaleDate)
             };
```

Unfortunately you can't use `ToList()` method with Linq to Entities. So either map anonymous objects manually to your `EmployeeDetails` or change `LastSalesDates` type to `IEnumerable<DateTime>`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an association in your model between employees and latestSales? Have you checked SQL Profiler or other profiling tools to see the SQL that's generated? Make sure the ToList() isn't issuing a separate query for each employee.

If you can live with a result structure as `IEnumerable<EmployeeId, IEnumerable<DateTime>>`, you could consider modifying this to be:

```
var result = (from e in employees
        select new EmployeeDetails
        {
                EmployeeId = e.employeeId,
                LastSaleDates = (from lsd in latestSales
                                 where e.employeeId equals lsd.EmployeeId
                                 select lsd.SaleDate)
        };
```

I have some more general recommendations at http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-Database-Performance-hints to help track issues down.

Comment: +1 for nice general recommendations. Btw there is another good tool you didn't mention in article [Entity Framework Profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky actually I did include it. EfProf.com redirects to that one, but it doesn't hurt to mention it again. FWIW, the MiniProfiler was written by the guys here at Stack to perf tune this site, so feel free to give them some love as well.